ArcGis crashes when clicking on point when using LayerList
I am having issues with ArcGis crashing when I click on a point on the map when I use LayerList in my application, the same code without the LayerList works fine.
import ArcGISMap from "@arcgis/core/Map";
import MapView from "@arcgis/core/views/MapView";
import GraphicsLayer from "@arcgis/core/layers/GraphicsLayer"
import Graphic from "@arcgis/core/Graphic";
import Point from "@arcgis/core/geometry/Point"
import SimpleMarkerSymbol from "@arcgis/core/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol";
import * as ApiUtils from './ApiResult';
import LayerList from "@arcgis/core/widgets/LayerList"
import PopupTemplate from "@arcgis/core/PopupTemplate.js";


const map = new ArcGISMap({
  basemap: "streets-vector",
});

getIpInfo()
  .then(apiResults => {
    if (Array.isArray(apiResults)) {


        const groupedByCountries = ApiUtils.splitByCountry(apiResults);

        groupedByCountries.forEach((countryGroup: ApiUtils.ApiResult[]) => {
          var featureLayer = new GraphicsLayer({
            title: countryGroup.at(0).IpBatchResult.country
          });

          countryGroup.forEach((batchResult) => {
          const pointGraphic = drawMarker(batchResult);
          featureLayer.add(pointGraphic);
        });

        map.layers.add(featureLayer);

      });



    } else {
      console.error('apiResults is not an array within .then():', apiResults);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching IP info:', error);
  });
  


const view = new MapView({
  map: map,
  container: "viewDiv",
  center: [18.0649, 59.3326],   // Stockholm
}); 

const layerList = new LayerList({
  view: view
});
view.ui.add(layerList, {
  position: "top-left"
});


view.when(() => {
  console.log("Map and View are ready");
});

Removing these rows in the code stops the error from occurring.
const layerList = new LayerList({
  view: view
});
view.ui.add(layerList, {
  position: "top-left"
});

Error message:
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$hostElement$')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$hostElement$')
    at forceUpdate (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:1659:33)
    at http://localhost:8080/vendors-node_modules_esri_calcite-components_dist_components_calcite-action-bar_js.bundle.js:81:92
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at overflowActions (http://localhost:8080/vendors-node_modules_esri_calcite-components_dist_components_calcite-action-bar_js.bundle.js:58:28)
    at ActionBar.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendors-node_modules_esri_calcite-components_dist_components_calcite-action-bar_js.bundle.js:246:64)
    at invokeFunc (http://localhost:8080/vendors-node_modules_esri_calcite-components_dist_components_debounce_js.bundle.js:419:19)
    at trailingEdge (http://localhost:8080/vendors-node_modules_esri_calcite-components_dist_components_debounce_js.bundle.js:468:14)
    at timerExpired (http://localhost:8080/vendors-node_modules_esri_calcite-components_dist_components_debounce_js.bundle.js:456:14)

Packages:
├── @arcgis/core@4.29.10
├── html-webpack-plugin@5.6.0
├── ts-loader@9.5.1
├── typescript@5.4.5
├── webpack-cli@5.1.4
├── webpack-dev-server@5.0.4
└── webpack@5.91.0

Any suggestions to try and fix this would be appreciated.
